# Save Strokes of inkManager in localStorage - windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, local-storage

well i try a lot of things but i don't really understand everything of save in localstorage. I know how its work since the camera, but i don't know how to make it with inkManager. If you're any ideas ?

This is my code to save where the user wants, but i would like to "auto-save" in localstorage :

```
private async void save_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inkManager.GetStrokes().Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker save = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
                save.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
                save.DefaultFileExtension = ".jpg";
                save.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPG", new string[] { ".jpg" });
                StorageFile filesave = await save.PickSaveFileAsync();
                IOutputStream ab = await filesave.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                if (ab != null)
                    await _inkManager.SaveAsync(ab);

              //  await save.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "merge1.jpg");

                if (save != null)
                {
                    Clipboard.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/merge1.jpg"));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy finally :

```
StorageFile myMerge = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myimg.png");
IOutputStream ac = await myMerge.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
if (ac != null)
    await _inkManager.SaveAsync(ac);
```